# How to store a block definition that returns something, in a local variable

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks, typedef

This seems a little strange to me that when my `block` does not returns anything, I can capture it in a variable before passing it to a consumer metod. But as soon I add a return value to the block `typedef`, I start getting waring

**Scenario 1**: Block does not returns anything
//declaration

```
typedef void (^MYConfigureBlock)(MYFeedCell *cell, NSIndexPath *indexPath);
```

//usage

```
  MYConfigureBlock block  = ^(MYFeedCell *cell, NSIndexPath *indexPath){
    [cell setActionDelegate:self];
    return nil;
};

MYFeedSource *fds = [[MYFeedSource alloc]initWithTableView:self.tableView
                                                    configurationBlock:block];
[fds setErrorMessage:@"No feeds yet. Is everyone even alive?"];
self.feedDataSource = fds;
```

Every thing works perfect in the above piece of code unless I go ahead and do:

**Problem here**

```
typedef MYFeedCell* (^MYConfigureBlock)(MYFeedCell *cell, NSIndexPath *indexPath);
```

Now how can I re-write the following statements so that there is no error. And why does this not works as usual with a return type?

```
MYConfigureBlock block  = ^(MYFeedCell *cell, NSIndexPath *indexPath){
    [cell setActionDelegate:self];
    return nil;
};
```

The error is

> Sending 'MYFeedCell *' to parameter of incompatible type 'MYConfigureBlock' (aka 'MYFeedCell *(^)(MYFeedCell *__strong, NSIndexPath *__strong)')

The code that uses the block

```
- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)aTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {

            self.cellConfigureBlock(nil, indexPath);
}
```

Comment: The first parameter is different in the declaration and use; (`UITableViewCell *cell` and `MYFeedCell *cell`).

Comment: fixed it. i typed the question so please ignore the parameters and variable names. thanks though

Comment: So it looks like the error is in the code that calls `block`.  Post that.

Comment: do you want to see the declaration of the init method? `-(instancetype)initWithTableView:(UITableView*)aTableView configurationBlock:(MYConfigureBlock)block`

Comment: No, I'd like to see the code that *uses* `block`.

Comment: `- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)aTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {        self.cellConfigureBlock(nil, indexPath);}
` ignore the nil in the argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to include the block's return type in the block signature because the compiler cannot infer the block's return type if you return `nil`. Try this:

```
MYConfigureBlock block = ^ MyFeedCell* (MYFeedCell *cell, NSIndexPath *indexPath){
    [cell setActionDelegate:self];
    return nil;
};
```

Note that your original code does not raise a compile error if you return a `MyFeedCell` object because the compiler can infer the return type:

```
MYConfigureBlock block = ^(MYFeedCell *cell, NSIndexPath *indexPath){
    [cell setActionDelegate:self];
    return cell;
};
```

Comment: perfect! it works . I was trying something similar but with wrong arrangement.

Answer (score -1):

```
    /** PROBLEM is the nil return*/
    //  return nil;

    //SHOULD return a valid type,which is expected.----Here Cell object should return.
    return cell;
```